# Different Windows In HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

While creating a website, I found that browsing others' sites makes it easier to visualise what I want to do. I found a certain website which seemed to have the browser window set up in a way which allowed for separate "windows" on the screen at once. So, if you scroll one part of the screen the *rest* of the screen won't do so, only the part which you scrolled. Likewise when you scroll the entire screen, some elements *don't* scroll with it, instead they appear to stay fixed in place.

What I am looking for Is a way of implementing this into my site - similar to this "example":

```
[...]
<window position="some-number" size="some-number">
    <!-- not a real element -->
    [...]
</window>
[...]
```

Is there a general way of doing this? Have you got to program this behaviour in JavaScript?

Comment: Are we talking about `iframes`, `parallax-elements`, or something else entirely? Your question is not very clear. It would be better if you included some of these websites as examples in your questions, and maybe even an image of what you're trying to get at.

Comment: so overflow and position fixed? or iframes, or many other things like that?

Comment: Similar to this very website, how the sidebar doesn't scroll with the rest of the window.

Comment: _"Is there a general way of doing this?"_ — there isn't a "general" way because the things you describe can all be different things, implemented in different ways. AP mentions iframes; epascarello and cs1349459 mention position:fixed; if an element has a set size and its content is "bigger" than that, overflow:scroll or overflow:auto will make a scrollable area. And no, you probably won't need javascript to do these things in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way for elements to stay in their spot when you scroll is to use the `position: fixed` CSS statement. See the example.

```css
#notscrolling {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrolling">
  <p>
    This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will
    scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>This will scroll<br>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="notscrolling">
  <p>this will not scroll</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the leftmost `p` scrolls, but the rightmost `p` does not.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using css styles like position: fixed/sticky to the html element you don't want to scroll.

The best possible solution would be to use React
Since React help us to create your own custom component so you can easily create
and use it like the way you defined the usage above